# Picards iteration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem
$xy'-y^2 -1 = 0$ with 
$x>0$ , $y(1)=0$

Write the differential equation as an integral equation $y(x) = L[x; y(x)]$ and define the
Picard iterates by $y_{n+1}(x) = L[x; yn(x)]$. Taking $y_0(x) = 0$, and $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$.

I started by using $f(x,y) = \frac{y^2+1}{x}$.

Inserting this and the inital condition into the equation $y= \alpha + \int\limits^x_{x_0} f(s,y(s)) ds $

I get $y= 0 + \int\limits^x_{x_0} y(s)^2 +1 dy$

I am confused on where to go from here and if my input is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case $x_0=1$ and $y(x_0)=0$. The integral equation is
$$
y(x)=0+\int_1^x\frac{(y(s))^2+1}{s}\,ds=\int_1^x\frac{(y(s))^2+1}{s}\,ds.
$$
The iteration starts with $y_0(x)=0$. Then
$$
y_1(x)=\int_1^x \frac{(y_0(s))^2+1}{s}\,ds=\ln x.
$$
The next term in the iterated sequence is
$$
y_2(x)=\int_1^x \frac{(y_1(s))^2+1}{s}\,ds=\int_1^x \frac{(\ln s)^2+1}{s}\,ds=\ln x+\frac{(\ln x)^3}{3}.
$$
And so on.